# Change database ownership SQL Server 2012 Express

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012

I'm trying to change the owner of a database using the alter authorization statement.

Statement:

```
ALTER AUTHORIZATION ON DATABASE::spentlytestlocal TO renspently
```

Error:

> Cannot find the principal 'username', because it does not exist or you do not have permission

I'm sure I assigned the user permission to take ownership, but any help and direction is greatly appreciated.

Comment: sure sorry for the confusion,

`ALTER AUTHORIZATION ON DATABASE:: tablename TO username`

Cannot find the principal 'username', because it does not exist or you do not have permission.

Comment: yeah I'm currently deleting and remaking the users and database in hopes of getting it to work

Comment: `ALTER AUTHORIZATION ON DATABASE::[DB_Name] TO [Login_Name];`  Note that a database owner is a SQL Server login (not a database user).

Comment: Thanks a lot, sorry in the documentation I'm referring it mentions changing the ownership to a "User" which I thought meant the entity. To clarify database owners can only be Logins?

Comment: Unfortunately, many people use `user` and `login` interchangeably.  In SQL Server, they are not the same thing.  I'm wondering if MS made the same mistake [in their documentation](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190909(v=sql.105).aspx).  With the possible exception of Contained Databases, I don't think a db can be owned by anything other than a SQL Server login.  Although deprecated, the [sp_changedbowner](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178630(v=sql.110).aspx) system stored proc has a `@loginame` parameter, but no @parameter for a database user.

Comment: Thanks again you've been a great help! =)

Comment: Well, I may have learned something new today.  I changed a db owner as follows: `EXEC sp_changedbowner @loginame = 'acme\WCoyote'`  WCoyote has no SQL Server login on the instance, but he is a domain admin.  Maybe he has connectivity/access to the SQL Server instance via `BUILTIN\Users` (or some other SQL Login tied to an active directory group).  This might be drifting off topic... Can anyone else add some insight?

Comment: Some small insight: apparently that feature is deprecated in SQL Server versions 2012+. Although this is only from what I read not from actual experience (I am an SQL Server noob)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For this to work, two things must be true, per [Books Online](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187359.aspx):

> Server objects (such as databases) must be owned by a server principal
>   (a login).

This means the account you want to give ownership must have a login on the server (not just a user in the database -- it is possible to have users without logins if you restore from a backup).

And second,

> Requires TAKE OWNERSHIP permission on the entity. If the new owner is
>   not the user that is executing this statement, also requires either,
>   1) IMPERSONATE permission on the new owner if it is a user or login;
>   or 2) if the new owner is a role, membership in the role, or ALTER
>   permission on the role; or 3) if the new owner is an application role,
>   ALTER permission on the application role.

Which means, in practice, that you need to be a sysadmin. One common instance of where you're not a sysadmin is if SQL Express has been configured to have local admins as sysadmins, but you don't start Management Studio with elevated permissions.

Comment: So what I am trying to do is make a user I create the owner of the database I specify. My understanding is that I have to map the user I create to a login on the server?

Comment: No, it's the other way around -- you create a login, and then you can assign ownership to that login. The login is not required to also be a user in the database (though it's not disallowed either). Logins are found under [server] -> Security -> Logins; they're database-independent.

Comment: Hmm, I'll give it a shot and consult further, Thanks!!

Comment: So what I've done is create a login and mapped it to a table. Under the user property it says dbo, however when I try and change the mapping to the user I define it does not allow it.

Comment: Your comment makes no sense to me -- you cannot map a login "to a table". Creating a login is as simple as `CREATE LOGIN [name] FROM WINDOWS` (if a Windows credential) or `CREATE LOGIN [name] WITH PASSWORD '[password]'` (for an SQL credential). After that, if you are sysadmin, `ALTER AUTHORIZATION` should just work.

Comment: Sorry user not table, I still get the error stated in the question.